# Tablesorter 2.0 Plugin and Tables with Nested HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sorting, html-table, tablesorter

I am using the Tablesorter plugin from https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html and I have the following table in an MVC Razor view.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
    decimal? vatValue = (item.UnitPrice * item.Quantity) * 0.2M;
    decimal? goodsValue = (item.UnitPrice * item.Quantity);
    <tr>
        <td class="product-title" data-thumbnail="/_includes/img/uploads/product-thumb.jpg"><span>@item.ProductName</span>
        </td>
        <td class="product-id">
            <span class="hl">Product code: </span>
            @item.ProductCode
        </td>
        <td class="price">&pound;@item.UnitPrice 
            <small class="hl">unit price</small>
        </td>
        <td class="units">
            <input type="number" class="choose-quantity" placeholder="0" value="@item.Quantity" min="0" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td class="vat">
            <small class="hl">VAT:</small>
            &pound;@(vatValue)
        </td>
        <td class="goods-value">
            <small class="hl">Goods value:</small>
            &pound;@(goodsValue)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

The VAT column and Goods value column do not numerically. I understand why this, and its because we have a nested  tag inside that  which is being sorted on and the plugin is likely interpreting the HTML as part of the string to sort by and thus not sorting numerically.

Is there anyway I can get around this? Any configuration setting I can set on this table to enable it to just look for the numerics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest if the values were wrapped in a span:

```
<tr>
    <td class="product-title" data-thumbnail="/_includes/img/uploads/product-thumb.jpg">
        <span>@item.ProductName</span>
    </td>
    <td class="product-id">
        <span class="hl">Product code: </span>
        @item.ProductCode
    </td>
    <td class="price">
        <span>&pound;@item.UnitPrice</span>
        <small class="hl">unit price</small>
    </td>
    <td class="units">
        <input type="number" class="choose-quantity" placeholder="0" value="@item.Quantity" min="0" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td class="vat">
        <small class="hl">VAT:</small>
        <span>&pound;@(vatValue)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="goods-value">
        <small class="hl">Goods value:</small>
        <span>&pound;@(goodsValue)</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then you can use the [`textExtraction` function](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textextraction) to target the span & extract out the relevant information ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/677/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textExtraction: {
            // header class names
            '.price, .vat, .goods-value' : function (node) {
                return $(node).find('span').text();
            }
        },
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
    });
});
```

*Note* the class names used to target the columns must match the class names of the cells in the `thead`, not the cells in the `tbody`.

Comment: This is very similar to what I did in fact. I had this problem and another whereby the sort wasn't working because of encoded &pound; character codes. I've written a hidden span into each field, and put this first. It's not seen in the table but allows the search to work effecively.

May I also say, fantastic work on your plugin! Exceptionally helpful, keep up the good work, thanks!